# Discovery of photon

Tags: photons, resource-recommendations, history

Is there a good book describing the story about the discovery of photon? What are the references for the very first works on the photons?

Comment: probably better asked on [hsm.se].

Comment: Read about Newton's corpuscles of light, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpuscular_theory_of_light

Comment: Not looking for 1-page descriptions. Any references from the 1st decade of the 1900s to the 3rd decade?

Comment: Start with Einstein's paper.   English translation here:  http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys2170/phys2170_sp15/Library_files/A.%20Einstein,%20Ann.%20Phys.%2017,%20132%201905.pdf

Comment: Yes, something like this. This is 1905. Can you please suggest more from 1905 to 1930? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here http://www.particleadventure.org/other/history/quantumt.html searching for "photon" in the page

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to *History of Science and Mathematics*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not within our site's scope.

Comment: P.S. @Yashas Note that if a question belongs on another site, that itself isn't a _reason_ for it to be off topic here.

Comment: You should have a look at abraham pais's book Inward Bound.